# How can I return the decrement of the previous value with each new call of one function?

Tags: javascript

I have a function named `decrement(number)` that returns another function. I need to create a new instance with `decrement(number)` with each call of which the return value is reduced by one except for the first. For example:

```
let a = decrement(5);

console.log(a()); // -> 5
console.log(a()); // -> 4
console.log(a()); // -> 3
console.log(a()); // -> 2
console.log(a()); // -> 1
console.log(a()); // -> 0
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make use of the concept of [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Remember, a function should be returned from `decrement`. And since you want access to the initial value (5 in this case) for every function execution, that value has to be out of the scope of the returned function body so it can be closed over. That way it can be accessed in each execution.

```js
const decrement = (init) => {
  let val = init;
  return () => {
    return init--;
  };

};

let a = decrement(5);


console.log(a());
console.log(a());
console.log(a());
console.log(a());
console.log(a());

let b = decrement(3);


console.log(b());
console.log(b());
console.log(b());
console.log(b());
console.log(b());
```

Another function created out of decrement will have its own `val` and `init` so you are good to go.

This can also be done without having the temporary `val` variable. `init` is also a variable which will be available to each execution of the inner function.

```
const decrement = (init) => {
  return () => {
    return init--;
  };
};
```